# writing out binary files using xcode

Tags: c++, xcode

I'm using xcode 6 to code up a C++ file-based array list (vector) for my Data abstractions course. This, of course, requires writing out binary files. I'm using the C-library functions (fopen, fclose,fread,fwrite,fseek, etc.) since I like those more than the C++ functions. I'm having no issues with my code per se. Everything's working fine, but the issue comes when I execute. 
Xcode will "run" everything, but it won't give me out a binary file. I think this has something to do with xcode itself not writing out these files since, all in all, it's a pretty costly thing to do. I can do it through the terminal using g++ but it would be a lot easier if I could do it through the xcode compiler so I'm not having to switch to a terminal window every time to test my code. Let me know if you need any clarification and thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The issue might be your working directory not being set correctly inside Xcode.

The file is probably getting written, just not to the right place (or the place you expect it).